# When trying to prune hidden dirs with the find command it seems to "prune" hidden files in top dir?

Tags: find, csh

In the code below I would expect to see find_examples_out/.t1, find_examples_out/.t2 and find_examples_out/.s1 files printed by the find command but they are excluded for some reason. They show up in the sub directories just fine.

Test script:

```
#!/bin/csh 
# GNU find version 4.1.20

find -version
mkdir find_examples_out
cd find_examples_out
set FILES = (t1 .t1 t2 .t2 s1 .s1)
set DIRS  = (.hidden normal notnormal another)

foreach f ( $FILES )
   touch $f
end

foreach i ( $DIRS )
   mkdir $i
   cd $i
   foreach f ( $FILES )
      touch $f
   end
   cd ..
end
echo "Files present:"
ls -AR

echo
echo "Give me all files but exclude some paths:"
find .                     \
   \(                      \
      -path "\.?.*"        \
      -o -path "*normal*"  \
   \)                      \
   -prune                  \
   -o                      \
                           \
   \(                      \
      -type f              \
   \)                      \
   -print

cd ..
rm -rf find_examples_out
```

Here is the output:

```
GNU find version 4.1.20
 Files present:
.:
another  .hidden  normal  notnormal  s1  .s1  t1  .t1  t2  .t2

./another:
s1  .s1  t1  .t1  t2  .t2

./.hidden:
s1  .s1  t1  .t1  t2  .t2

./normal:
s1  .s1  t1  .t1  t2  .t2

./notnormal:
s1  .s1  t1  .t1  t2  .t2

Give me all files but exclude some paths:
./t1
./t2
./s1
./another/t1
./another/.t1
./another/t2
./another/.t2
./another/s1
./another/.s1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: A csh script should probably have `#!/bin/csh -f` at the top.  The `-f` tells it not to read your startup files (`.cshrc` and `.login`), which (a) makes it start faster, and (b) avoids dependencies on your own personal environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've overlooked something, the -path switch to find compares the pattern given to the **path including the filename**.

Ergo, your **-path "\.?.*"** switch will match the hidden files ".t1" etc.

FWIW: in the version of find that I have (v4.4.2), the argument to -path is a shell pattern, not a regex. However, I use bash and have never used csh, so perhaps that makes a difference too.

EDIT: I tried to add this as a comment, but it keeps destroying the formatting.

You could use this to achieve what (I think) you are trying to achieve:

```
find . \( \( -path "\.?.*" -type d \) -o -path "*normal*" \) -prune -o \( -type f \) -print
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks for clearing it up for me. It seems like the option "-path" is not a very good name since it will filter filenames as well as paths...